# Accelerate OpenGL 2D on Python3

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, linux, opengl

I'm using OpenGL to draw about 20 circles. Each circle has 2 lines, ~10 segments, and all of them have different colors and lengths. Frames per Second are around 4.

How can I optimize this to run faster, with higher frame-rates? I am using Python 3 on Ubuntu.

```
class ScreenOpenGL(Screen):
def __init__(self,layers,layers_lock):
    """ Инициализирует экран и запускает его, потом всю программу """
    Screen.__init__(self,"OpenGL",layers,layers_lock)

    self.window = 0
    self.quad = None
    self.keypress = []

    print("Fuck")
    # self.infoScreen = ScreenCursesInfo()
    self.infoScreen = ScreenStandartInfo()
    GLUT.glutInit(sys.argv)
    GLUT.glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT.GLUT_RGBA | GLUT.GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT.GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT.GLUT_DEPTH)
    GLUT.glutInitWindowSize(640, 480)
    GLUT.glutInitWindowPosition(400, 400)
    self.window = GLUT.glutCreateWindow(b"Project Evoluo alpha")
    GLUT.glutDisplayFunc(self._loop) # Функция, отвечающая за рисование
    GLUT.glutIdleFunc(self._loop) # При простое перерисовывать
    GLUT.glutReshapeFunc(self._resize) # изменяет размеры окна
    GLUT.glutKeyboardFunc(self._keyPressed) # Обрабатывает нажатия
    self._initGL(640, 480)
    field_params(640, 480)
    print("Fuck")

def run(self):
    # для threading
    GLUT.glutMainLoop()

def _initGL(self,Width,Height):
    GL.glShadeModel(GL.GL_SMOOTH); 
    GL.glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)    # This Will Clear The Background Color To Black
    GL.glClearDepth(1.0)                   # Enables Clearing Of The Depth Buffer
    GL.glDepthFunc(GL.GL_LESS)                # The Type Of Depth Test To Do
    GL.glHint(GL.GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL.GL_NICEST)
    GL.glEnable(GL.GL_BLEND);                         # Enable Blending
    GL.glLineWidth(1.);
    GL.glDisable(GL.GL_LINE_SMOOTH)
    GL.glBlendFunc(GL.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    self.width = Width
    self.height = Height
    self.quad = GLU.gluNewQuadric()
    GLU.gluQuadricNormals(self.quad, GLU.GLU_SMOOTH)
    GLU.gluQuadricTexture(self.quad, GL.GL_TRUE)

def _resize(self,Width,Height):
    if Height == 0:
        Height = 1
    self.width = Width
    self.height = Height
    field_params(Width,Height)

    GL.glViewport(0, 0, Width, Height)       # Reset The Current Viewport And Perspective Transformation
    GL.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION)
    GL.glLoadIdentity()

    GL.glOrtho(0.0,Width,0.0,Height,-1.0,1.0)

    GL.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW)                   # Select The Modelview Matrix
    GL.glLoadIdentity()

def update(self):
    GLUT.glutSwapBuffers()

def clear(self):
    GL.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    GL.glLoadIdentity()                    # Reset The View 

def write(self,pos,str):
    pass

def __del__(self):
    del(self.infoScreen)
    GLUT.glutDestroyWindow(self.window)
    self._end()
    # sys.exit()

def getch(self):
    if self.keypress != []:
        # print
        return self.keypress.pop(-1)[0]
    else:
        return None

def _keyPressed(self,*args):
    if args != None:
        self.keypress.append(args)
        print(self.keypress)

def _draw_prepare(self):
    del(self._layers)
    self._layers = []
    for layer in layers:
        if layer.__class__ == LayerObjects:
            self._layers.append([layer.type,copy.deepcopy(layer.get_objs()),copy.copy(layer._attacked)])

def draw_eyes(self,vis,r_max,dphi):
    for x in range(0,7):
        GLU.gluPartialDisk(self.quad,
            1,
            vis[x][0] * r_max,
            5,
            3,
            - ((x - 3) * 15 + 7.5 + dphi / pi * 180) + 90,
            15)

def draw_sensitivity(self,sens,r_max,dphi):
    for x in range(0,5):
        GLU.gluPartialDisk(self.quad,
            1,
            sens[x] * r_max,
            5,
            3,
            - (52.5 + (x+1) * 51 + dphi / pi * 180) + 90,
            51)   
    pass

def draw_obj(self,obj,_id,pos,circle,lines,attacked):
    # Кружок
    GL.glLoadIdentity()
    GL.glTranslatef(pos[0]-1,pos[1]-1,0)
    red,green,blue = obj.color # берём цвет
    GL.glColor3f(red,green,blue)
    GLU.gluDisk(self.quad,*circle)

    #Глазки
    GL.glColor3f(1-red,1-green,1-blue)
    try:
        eyes = obj.eyes
    except NameError:
        pass
    else:
        self.draw_eyes(obj.eyes.eyes,obj.radius * k_screen,obj.pos[1])
    # Прикосновения
    GL.glColor3f(1,0,0)
    try:
        sensitivity = obj.sensitivity
    except NameError:
        pass
    else:
        self.draw_sensitivity(obj.sensitivity._sens,obj.radius * k_screen,obj.pos[1])
    # Полосочки
    GL.glBegin(GL.GL_LINES)
    for color,x,y in lines:
        GL.glColor3f(*color)
        GL.glVertex3f(0,0,0)
        GL.glVertex3f(x,y,0)
    GL.glEnd()

def draw(self,layer):
    global width,height
    if layer[0] == "Layer Objects":
        attacked = layer[2]
        for obj in layer[1]:
            #Стрелочки-направления
            pos = [int(x) for x in obj.get_pos_screen()]
            positions = [pos,]
            radius_scr = obj.radius * k_screen
            att = Vector(radius_scr * (1 +obj._attack_range*obj._attack),
                    obj.pos[1],
                    isPolar = True
                    ) 
            speed = obj.speed[0] * k_screen * 5

            if pos[0] < radius_scr:
                positions.append([pos[0] + self.width,pos[1]])
            if pos[0] + radius_scr > self.width:
                positions.append([pos[0] - self.width,pos[1]])
            if pos[1] < radius_scr:
                positions.append([pos[0],pos[1] + self.height])
            if pos[1] + radius_scr > self.height:
                positions.append([pos[0],pos[1] - self.height])

            for ps in positions:
                self.draw_obj(obj,obj._id, ps , [0,obj.radius*k_screen,20,1], [ [ (1,0,0) , att.x, att.y ], [ (0,0,1) , speed.x, speed.y] ] , attacked)

    self.infoScreen.draw()
```

Function code that draws:

```
    def _draw_prepare(self):
    """ Копирует из глобальной переменной всё, что ей нужно """
    self._layers = copy.deepcopy(layers)
def _loop(self):
    global tick
    if (self.ch == b'q') or (self.ch == b'\xb1') or (self.ch == 27) or (self.ch == 113):
        isEnd = True
        self.__del__()
        del(self)
        return 0
    elif (self.ch == b's'):
        self._is_draw = not self._is_draw
        print("changed to %d" %self._is_draw)
    else:
        if (self.last_tick != tick) and (self._is_draw):
            self.layers_lock.acquire(1)
            self._draw_prepare()
            self.layers_lock.release()
            self.last_tick = tick
    # рисует сцену
    return self._main()
def _main(self):
    global tick
    self.clear()
    if self._is_draw:
        for layer in self._layers:
            self.draw(layer)
    self.update()
    self.ch = self.getch()
```

And on [GitHub](https://github.com/ktulhy-kun/project_evoluo/blob/master/evoluo.py#L213)

Comment: First, we're a code review...not here to fix code. Having said that, your code does not follow *any* style-rules. Sometimes there are spaces between operators, sometimes there are not, sometimes there are spaces after a comma, sometimes not...sometimes there are English comments, sometimes they're Russian(?).

Comment: A bad algorithm is not a broken algorithm. Voted to leave open. Further more, all facets of the code are up for review, not the performance.

Comment: This post [was mentioned on meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2206/41243).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really sure why this line is neccesary.

```
print("Fuck")
```

Unless `"Fuck"` is Russian for something, this should be removed.

In addition, using `%` for string formatting is deprecated. One should be using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) instead. `str.format` supports normal, positional, and named parameters. Here's an example:

```
# str.format without positional or named parameters
print("{} {}".format("Hello", "world"))

# str.format with positional parameters
print("{1} {0}".format("world", "Hello"))

# str.format with named parameters
print("{word1} {word2}".format(word1="Hello", word2="world"))
```

I also noticed that you're mixing English and Russian comments. I'd recommend sticking to one language or the other.

In the class `ScreenOpenGL` you have a "private" method named `_initGL`. Is there any reason why the contents of this method can't just be part of `__init__`?

You also don't need parentheses around Boolean conditions. For example, `(self.last_tick != tick)` would become `self.last_tick != tick`.

Finally, I noticed that you're mixing a lot of naming styles. Variables and functions should be `snake_case`, and classes should be `PascalCase`. If a variable is a constant (un-changing value), it should be in `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE`.

Comment: So, "print("Fuck")" used for debug :)
Other comment's -- thank, but this code was written a long ago, and most of things I already know. Thank anyway!